# Google API Won't Let me Retrieve Gmail Messages Using OAuth in PHP (returns 401 - Login Required)

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm at my wit's end on this.  I have the OAuth setup and working (i.e. I'm able to retrieve access/refresh tokens after authorizing), but when I try to connect to my Gmail inbox, Google just spits back a 401 with a JSON saying that login is required.

I'm using the beta google-api-php-client library and I haven't been able to find any non-deprecated solutions to this.  What's weird is that I was able to retrieve a message on the very first test, but after that (without any code changes) it started returning a 401 instead and it's driving me bonkers.

Here's the relevant code in question:

```
<?php

public function __construct( $autoAuth = FALSE )
{
    require_once( 'scripts/gmail/config.class.php' );
    require_once( 'scripts/gmail/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php' );

    $this->appName = gmail_config::$appName;
    $this->clientId = gmail_config::$clientId;
    $this->clientSecret = gmail_config::$clientSecret;

    $this->client = new Google_Client();

    // Using the JSON also returned a 401 so I tried it without; no change.
    //$this->client->setAuthConfig( 'scripts/gmail/gmail_client_id.json' );
    $this->client->setClientId( gmail_config::$clientId );
    $this->client->setClientSecret( gmail_config::$clientSecret );

    // On user auth screen, it keeps saying I'm only requesting "offline access".  Any idea why?
    $this->client->addScope( 'https://mail.google.com/' );
    $this->client->addScope( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose' );

    $this->client->setRedirectUri( '(redacted)' );

    // Required for generating a refresh token.  --Kris
    $this->client->setAccessType( 'offline' );
    $this->client->setApprovalPrompt( 'force' );

    $this->authURL = $this->client->createAuthUrl();

    $this->SQLInit();

    if ( $autoAuth === TRUE )
    {
        if ( !( $this->auth() ) )
        {
            print 'User authorization required : ' . $this->authURL;
        }
    }
}

public function auth()
{
    $res = $this->SQLQuery( 'SELECT * FROM oauth_tokens WHERE service = ?', array( 'gmail' ) );

    if ( !empty( $res ) && !empty( $res['accessToken'] ) && !empty( $res['refreshToken'] ) && !empty( $res['issued'] ) && !empty( $res['lastRefresh'] ) )
    {
        $this->accessToken = json_decode( $res['accessToken'], TRUE );
        $this->refreshToken = $res['refreshToken'];
        $this->tokenIssued = strtotime( $res['issued'] );
        $this->lastTokenRefresh = strtotime( $res['lastRefresh'] );

        if ( (time() - $this->lastTokenRefresh) >= 3600 )
        {
            $this->refreshToken();
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function refreshToken()
{
    $this->client->refreshToken( $this->refreshToken );
    $this->accessToken = $this->client->getAccessToken();

    $this->SQLQuery( 'DELETE FROM oauth_tokens WHERE service = ?', array( 'gmail' ), SQL_RETURN_AFFECTEDROWS );

    $this->SQLQuery( 'INSERT INTO oauth_tokens ( service, accessToken, refreshToken, lastRefresh ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, NOW() )', 
            array( 'gmail', json_encode( $this->accessToken ), $this->accessToken['refresh_token'] ), 
            SQL_RETURN_AFFECTEDROWS );
}

public function getMessagesTest( $limit = 5 )
{
    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail( $this->client );

    $optParams = [];
    $optParams['maxResults'] = $limit; // Return Only $limit Messages
    $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox

    $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages( 'me', $optParams ); // <-- THIS IS WHERE IT'S FAILING!
    $list = $messages->getMessages();

    $res = array();
    foreach ( $list as $key => $email )
    {
        $messageId = $email->getId(); // Grab Message

        $optParamsGet = [];
        $optParamsGet['format'] = 'full'; // Display message in payload

        $message = $service->users_messages->get( 'me', $messageId, $optParamsGet );
        $messagePayload = $message->getPayload();

        $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
        $parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();

        $body = $parts[0]['body'];
        $rawData = $body->data;
        $sanitizedData = strtr( $rawData, '-_', '+/' );
        $decodedMessage = base64_decode( $sanitizedData );

        $res[$key] = array();
        $res[$key]['message'] = $decodedMessage;
        $res[$key]['parts'] = $parts;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

In case it helps, here's where the tokens are being stored from the redirectUri endpoint:

```
    <?php

    try
    {
        $gmail = new gmail();
        $token = $gmail->client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( $params[1]['code'] );

        $sql->query( 'DELETE FROM oauth_tokens WHERE service = ?', array( 'gmail' ), SQL_RETURN_AFFECTEDROWS );
        $sql->query( 'INSERT INTO oauth_tokens ( service, accessToken, refreshToken, lastRefresh ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, NOW() )', array( 'gmail', json_encode( $token ), $token['refresh_token'] ) );
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        return array( 'status' => 500, 'error' => 'SQL error on insert : ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }
```

I've been Googling this for hours and nothing I've tried has had any effect.  I did try revisiting the authURL to refresh the tokens/etc but that didn't work.

I'd prefer a simple fix (i.e. maybe just some required thing that I'm missing?) over refactoring everything to use something else.  That said, I'm stumped.  Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?  If you need additional code/information, please let me know and I'll include it.

Thanks for your help!  This is blocking the whole project now so hopefully one of you will see what it is I'm missing....

**EDIT**

I added a var_dump( $this->client ) to getMessagesTest() as one of you suggested.  Here's the redacted output:

```
object(Google_Client)#10 (8) {
  ["auth":"Google_Client":private]=>
  object(Google\Auth\OAuth2)#11 (24) {
    ["authorizationUri":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri)#12 (7) {
      ["scheme":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(5) "https"
      ["userInfo":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["host":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(19) "accounts.google.com"
      ["port":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      NULL
      ["path":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(14) "/o/oauth2/auth"
      ["query":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["fragment":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["tokenCredentialUri":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri)#13 (7) {
      ["scheme":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(5) "https"
      ["userInfo":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["host":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(18) "www.googleapis.com"
      ["port":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      NULL
      ["path":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(16) "/oauth2/v4/token"
      ["query":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["fragment":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["redirectUri":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    string(47) "(my redirect URL)"
    ["clientId":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    string(72) "(my clientId).apps.googleusercontent.com"
    ["clientSecret":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    string(24) "(my client secret)"
    ["username":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["password":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["scope":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["state":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["code":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["issuer":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    string(72) "(my clientId).apps.googleusercontent.com"
    ["audience":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["sub":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["expiry":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    int(3600)
    ["signingKey":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["signingAlgorithm":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["refreshToken":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["accessToken":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["idToken":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["expiresIn":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["expiresAt":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["issuedAt":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["grantType":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    NULL
    ["extensionParams":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["http":"Google_Client":private]=>
  NULL
  ["cache":"Google_Client":private]=>
  NULL
  ["token":"Google_Client":private]=>
  NULL
  ["config":"Google_Client":private]=>
  array(23) {
    ["application_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_path"]=>
    string(26) "https://www.googleapis.com"
    ["client_id"]=>
    string(72) "(my clientId).apps.googleusercontent.com"
    ["client_secret"]=>
    string(24) "(my client secret)"
    ["redirect_uri"]=>
    string(47) "(my redirect URL)"
    ["state"]=>
    NULL
    ["developer_key"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["use_application_default_credentials"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["signing_key"]=>
    NULL
    ["signing_algorithm"]=>
    NULL
    ["subject"]=>
    NULL
    ["hd"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["prompt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["openid.realm"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["include_granted_scopes"]=>
    NULL
    ["login_hint"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["request_visible_actions"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["access_type"]=>
    string(7) "offline"
    ["approval_prompt"]=>
    string(5) "force"
    ["retry"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["cache_config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["token_callback"]=>
    NULL
    ["jwt"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["logger":"Google_Client":private]=>
  NULL
  ["deferExecution":"Google_Client":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["requestedScopes":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(24) "https://mail.google.com/"
    [1]=>
    string(45) "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose"
  }
}
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Oh and just to clarify, yes that code is contained within a class.  I chopped the class definition/etc code out of this post for the sake of brevity.

Comment: $this->client->setApprovalPrompt( 'force' );  <-- any special reason you have that?    Do a var dump on $this->client in getMessagesTest make sure its setting your access token

Comment: @DalmTo I added that in there because I read somewhere (I think another SO question) that you have to in order for the refresh token to be included in the JSON; it was coming up null before I added that, IIRC.

I'll try doing a var_dump on the client....

Comment: Ok I did the var_dump and added the output to the post.  Do you see anything that might be causing this?

Comment: 'offline'  will return a refresh token upon authentication .  Force is going to require that the user authenticate your code every time they come back.

Comment: Think you might be looking for this $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshToken);

Comment: You mean in my refreshToken() function or someplace else?

Comment: Its been a long time since I have done this but yes in that method you appear to be setting the refresh token and the access token.   The client library has a method that deals with that for you if you pass it the refresh token.

Comment: Ok I just tried that and it doesn't seem to have had any effect.  Here's the output I'm getting back from Google:   "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php  Try following this.   There is a probably with the client you are passing here $service = new Google_Service_Gmail( $this->client );

Comment: Ok I'll take a look again there.  I tried removing the setApprovalPrompt( 'force' ) line but that just resulted in the OAuth return from Google once again omitting the refresh_token (comes back in the JSON as null), which breaks the workflow because that token is needed to request new access tokens.

Comment: @DalmTo Oh and what did you mean by, "There is a probably with the client you are passing here $service = new Google_Service_Gmail( $this->client );"?  Is there something I should change about that line of code?

Comment: The refresh token is only returned the first time you authenticate the application the application should save it to see it again you need to remove the application in your google settings https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en.  Like I said its been a long time since I have done this.   $this->client does not probably have the refresh token that's what is causing your error.

Comment: So the refresh token never changes at all?  I.e. I refresh after 6 months of inactivity and, assuming no API changes, I should be able to get a new access token with the same refresh token?  If that's the case, I could modify the workflow if you think that's what might be causing this.  How do I go about getting $this->client to have the refresh token?  I thought I already was doing that in my refreshToken() function.

Comment: A refresh token does not expire.  However if it hasn't been used in six months then yes google will deactivate it.   Its best to just try and use it if it returns with an error then request auth again of the user.    If you had applied it correctly you would be seeing something in the var dump.   Try following one of the standard tutorials get that to work and then add the gmail stuff.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the problem was that the access token had expired and my refreshToken() function was rigged to manually check for expiration by comparing the current time to when it was stored in the database.  But since I'm using an idempotent REST API, I had set it up to delete and re-insert the tokens whenever user authorization occurs (i.e. by following the authURL in a browser).  As a result, the 'issued' timestamp was being reset whenever I impatiently went back to the authURL to try to obtain a new token, not realizing that it was just giving me the same expired access token as before each and every time.

Apparently, you *have* to use the refresh token to get a new one; i.e. even starting over with the authURL won't cut it.  I put it all together when I noticed that the client has a built-in isAccessTokenExpired() function, so I modified my ifcheck to use that and everything works now.

TL;DR:  My refresh code wasn't getting called because I incorrectly assumed that the access token is automatically refreshed when you have the user revisit the authURL.